# Why can I click on a link outside of its text element?

Tags: html, css

I'm building a forum and I have a link that can be clicked outside of its text, how can I undo it?
I also have an image inside a tag that can be clicked outside of its image, I want to undo that too.
I have tried - position: relative; but it didn't work.

---

Here is the HTML code of the image.

```
<div class="nav-list">
       <a class="home_A"href="Home.php">
          <img class="homeIcon" src="photos/icon.png">
       </a>
</div>
```

CSS of the image

```
.homeIcon{
    width: 200px;
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

---

CSS of the `<a>` link

```
.signinForm a{
margin: auto;
display:block;
text-align:center;
margin-top: 7px;
color: #006db6;
font-size: 20px;
}
```

HTML of the `<a>` link

```
<form method="POST" class="signinForm">
<ul>
    <li> <h1 class="signinH1">sign in</h1></li>
    <li> <input type="text" placeholder="User name"name="username_login"class="username" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['username_login'])){echo $_POST['username_login'];}?>" required></li>
    <li> <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password_login" class="password" value="<?php  if(isset($_POST['password_login'])){echo $_POST['password_login'];}?>" required></li>
    <li> <input type="submit" value="Log in"class="signinbutton"></li>
    <li><a href="signUp.php">Sign up</a></li>
</ul>

</form>
```

Thanks all.

Comment: So, you are saying that your anchor element is larger than its content and you want it to be the same size? In that case, would be helpful to see your css

Comment: "I have a link that can be clicked outside of its text" ???

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with your CSS styles for `<a>` tags and/or `<img>` tags.

My guess is that something like the following might fix your issue

```css
.homeIcon {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: It works but the image sticks to the right side instead of the center of the line, how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like:

```
img.homeIcon {
  display: inline-block;
}

div.home_A {
align-content:center;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center; // Not mandatory but useful
}
```

Comment: Tell me if this fit your needs! Have a nice day!

Comment: Hi, thank you but it doesn't work...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Assign `display: inline-block` of course, also use `object-fit:contain` on `<img>` and set the `line-height:` of `<a>` to 1 to 1.25 depending on how your font is setup but there's very little play in the value.

```css
:root {
  font: 1ch/1 'Segoe UI'
}

body {
  font-size: 2ch;
}

a {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  line-height: 1.15;
}

a,
img {
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: -3px;
}
```

```html
<div class='frame'>
  <a class="zOne" href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/2813224/zer00ne">
..::Zer00ne::..
  <img src='https://i.ibb.co/Kx33pSY/01.jpg'></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--HTML_CODE-->
<div class="nav-list">
   <a class="home_A"href="Home.php">
      <img class="homeIcon" src="photos/icon.png">
   </a>
</div>


<form method="POST" class="signinForm">
<ul>
<li> <h1 class="signinH1">sign in</h1></li>
<li> <input type="text" placeholder="User 
name"name="username_login"class="username" value="<?php 
if(isset($_POST['username_login'])){echo $_POST['username_login'];}?>" required> 
</li>
<li> <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password_login" 
class="password" value="<?php  if(isset($_POST['password_login'])){echo 
$_POST['password_login'];}?>" required></li>
<li> <input type="submit" value="Log in"class="signinbutton"></li>
<div class="signUp-block">
<li><a href="signUp.php">Sign up</a></li></div>
</ul>

</form>


/*CSS_CODE*/
.homeIcon{
width: 200px;
display:block;
margin:auto;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.signUp-block{
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: center;
}
.signinForm a{

margin: auto;
display:inline-block;

text-align:center;
margin-top: 7px;
color: #006db6;
font-size: 20px;
}
.homeIcon {
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).